# Code::Blocks profiler not including calls to library functions

Tags: c, optimization, codeblocks, profiler

I am trying to optimize a piece of code I've been working on for some time. My current target for optimization is a function that takes about 50% of the runtime of the program, and contains several calls to `memcpy()` which I am considering trying to eliminate. However, the profiler that ships with code::blocks (GNU GProf Profiler) does not seem to time calls to library functions as set up in Code::Blocks, so I am unable to tell if the `memcpy()` calls are the bottleneck.

Eliminating the calls is doable, but will be quite complex, so I would like to know in advance if it's really worth it. Is there any way to make the Code::Blocks profiler time calls to standard library functions? I can't seem to find any appropriate settings.

Comment: Would a usable temporary work-around be to introduce a small, local shell routine for `memcpy()` that you call instead?

Comment: Excellent idea. Not sure why I didn't think of that. Feel free to post that as an answer, I'll accept it.